# C++ Linked List Deep Copy Constructor and Assignment Overloaded

Tags: constructor, linked-list, copy, operator-keyword

```
#ifndef LIST
#define LIST

 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

typedef string ElementType;


 class List
{
  private:

 class Node
 {

 public:
  ElementType data;
  Node * next;

  Node()
  :data(ElementType()), next(NULL)
  {}

  Node(ElementType initData)
  :data(initData), next(NULL)
  {}

}; // end of Node class         

typedef Node * NodePointer;



  public:
  private:
  NodePointer first;
  int mySize;
  }; // end of List class
```

This is my overloaded assignment operator, im not sure what im doing wrong, but im beyond frustrated,I've searched the web and read different forums and cannot find a solution to do this, could someone please push me in the right direction, I left out all my public member functions, because none of them operate on my overloaded assignment and copy constructor, I just wanted you guys to get an idea of my layout

overloaded assignment operator

```
List & List::operator=(const List &rightSide)
{
if(this != &rightSide)
{
    this->~List();
}

NodePointer ptr = rightSide.first;
NodePointer cptr = ptr;

while(ptr != NULL)
{   
    cptr->next = new Node(ptr->data);
    cptr = cptr->next;
    ptr = ptr->next;
}

return *this;
```

}

this is my copy constructor

```
List::List(const List &source)
{
NodePointer ptr = source.first;
NodePointer cptr;

if(ptr == NULL)
{
    cerr << "Bad allocation, empty list" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

while(ptr != NULL)
{
    cptr = new Node(ptr->data);
    cptr->next =    ptr->next;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    ptr = ptr->next;
 }
 }
```